# SIGABRT when adding a constraint to a uiview

Tags: swift, debugging, autolayout

Once again auto layout has me scratching my head. I define a UIView and UITextField at the top of my class:

```
var urlField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
var barView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

I call my configuration method from viewWillAppear (so I know that self.view is all set):

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                configureURLBar()
    }
```

And I'm doing nothing special there.

```
func configureURLBar() {
    barView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    barView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    barView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    }
```

When it gets to the topAnchor constraint I get the exception, and I don't understand why.  If I reverse the 2nd and 3rd lines it doesn't blow up until it gets to the .topAnchor line, so that's the problem. I can ask a second question once I understand the reason for this exception (in case you're wondering what I'm trying to do): how do I add a user input (url) bar at the top of my UIWebView.  (that didn't work either - same results if I try to constrain against my self.webView which is displaying perfectly) Also: I call self.view.setNeedsDisplay() before viewWillAppear() is called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add your view to parent view first. After that you can add constraints.

Try this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) 
{
self.view.addSubview(barView)               
configureURLBar()
}
```

Comment: Of course! I need some coffee, then I'll write a checklist (steps) for auto layout. So many things to keep track of at once! Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 0):

Include your logic in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of in `viewWillAppear`... 
`viewDidLayoutSubviews` is a much better place to handle geometry

Comment: It still blows up on the same line.

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: just noticed the header

Comment: Not much: Thread 1: SIGABRT. Nothing appears in the console log (Debug area)